# Blazor wasm detect if the current page has a visible vertical scrollbar and subscribe to the scroll event

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm very new to Blazor programming, and I'm trying to perform "little things"... :)

I was looking for [How do i subscribe to onscroll event in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135574/how-do-i-subscribe-to-onscroll-event-in-blazor/75017125#75017125) in order to detect if the current window/document (not a particular DIV) is provided with a vertical scrollbar and eventually subscribe to it's scroll...

the provided post indicates a DIV solution, but what about "the whole document"?
TIA

Andrea